# Odd Reputation Number: 90 + 20 + 10 = 121?

Tags: support, reputation

It's not clear to me that this is because of the reputation drop issue earlier today.

My current reputation number here on meta is 121. I was curious to see how that number came about, so clicked on the [reputation history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/76337?tab=reputationhistory#sort-top) link for myself.

I saw a 90 and a 20 and a 10, and I believe I'm missing a 1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You, me, everyone gets a 1 to start off with, and your rep can never drop below 1 even if you get down-votes that should take you into negative territory.

I don't know whether there are reasons for this. Unless it's must have rep > 0 to post.

Comment: I could have sworn I started off with 100. Maybe it would have gone down below zero with the problem from earlier today?

Comment: I had 139 when I went to bed. I have 39 now. I think it got re-calced this morning.

Comment: @John - this was due to some kind of update that removed the +100 for users with accounts on other sites.  Its been discussed on a few other threads today.  It happened to me too.

Comment: Errr...138 starting out last night, sorry.

Comment: @RSolberg - if you do the math(s) his scores add up: 90 + 20 + 10 + the opening 1 = 121, his current score (as of this posting)

Comment: @Chris: When originally ported accounts from SO, you start with 100. This 100 got recalced/subtracted last night.

Comment: @Eric - yes I know that, but John's already taken that into account. Look at his expression again.

Comment: @John - it started with 101 - the 100 bonus which got removed after the shenanigans this morning and the usual starting 1.

Comment: @all: yeah, it's the "1" that attracted my attention. 100 + 90 + 20 + 10 - 100 is still 120, not 121.

Comment: @ChrisF: Maybe it started at 100 on serverfault, but 1 or 101 here? I'm very certain I was staring at "100" for a couple of days.

Comment: @John - I can't argue with that, though I did see a long tail of folks with 1 rep on the user pages. Maybe the 1 got added as part of the recalc as it's part of the algorithm & that wasn't run initially.

Answer (score 1):

You get one point to start with.

Answer (score 0):

There is a starting bounty for everybody of 1 point. maybe due to the errors in regard of account bounty of today, you lost your 100 rep from starting an account on meta coming from SO or SF. The recalc done does not know about the 100 starting rep.

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2092/ive-just-seen-my-rep-on-so-jump-by-100-is-this-due-to-a-rep-recalc) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2100/whats-happening-to-jeffs-rep-on-meta) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2103/how-did-i-just-go-down-150-rep-on-so).